# VueDemi not working when I try to import my vue 3 library in a vue 2.6 project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to implement a library that can run both Vue 2 and Vue 3 using VueDemi

After I followed the documentation, my library is not working in a Vue 2.6 project. I'm not receving any error or warning, the component it's just not displaying. ( I used Vue 3 in the library).

The funny part is that console.log works, but html is not rendering .

Any information would be useful. Thanks!

Below are my library informations

This is my  package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-library",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "main": "./dist/my-library-lib.umd.cjs",
  "module": "./dist/my-library-lib.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue-demi": "latest"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.0 || >=3.0.0"
  },
  "peerDependenciesMeta": {
    "@vue/composition-api": {
      "optional": true
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
    "vite": "^4.4.10",
    "vue": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

This is my vite.js.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { resolve } from 'path'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['vue-demi']
  },
  build: {
    lib: {
      // src/indext.ts is where we have exported the component(s)
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
      name: 'GlobalSearch',
      // the name of the output files when the build is run
      fileName: 'global-search-lib'
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
      // into your library
      external: ['vue-demi'],
      output: {
        // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
        // for externalized deps
        globals: {
          "vue-demi": "VueDemi",
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

This is the component that I imported in the project:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  mounted: function () {
    console.log('test')
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: vue-demi is to make the script part universal. This means that the template is compiled in a way it's incompatible with 2. There's major difference between 2 and 3 in this regard. I doubt it's possible to compile it in a way it's compatible with both. Probably there should be 2 different builds. See https://vitejs.dev/plugins/#official-plugins